# Predict Ethereum price up or down by given Bitcoin price

Tags: classification, regression

How would you proceed, if you have 2 parameters, for example, the price of the Bitcoin and the price of Ethereum for each day and you want to predict based on the Bitcoin price if Etherium will go “up” or “down”?  Some ideas or some tutorials in this area?

Answer (score 1):

So, the question asks how to predict the price Etherium given the price of Bitcoin.

It is worth doing some Explanatory Data Analysis (EDA) to see if there is a correlation between these two variables.

You might find that the relationship between the two variables is non-linear, which indicates that maybe the model that you would make with Bitcoin price feature is going to be too simple and will lead to undercutting. Therefore, it would be worth adding more complexity by increasing the number of features, which could also be correlated with Etherium prices.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  But what model do you prefer in such case: Classification or Regression?

Comment: Since you're trying to find a price, a continuous number, regression is the only option I think